# How to delete typed URL in Chrome and firefox

Tags: google-chrome, winapi, firefox, visual-c++

I am creating an application in vc++ that deletes the typed address from chrome and Firefox. Can anyone let me know how and where this information are stored. And how it can be done. Any relevant link you know can share it.